# Adding custom column to comments admin panel?

Tags: filters, comments

How do I add a new custom column to wordpress wp-admin/edit-comments.php page ? I tried this but did not work.

```
add_filter( 'manage_comments_custom_column',  'add_new_columns' );
function add_new_columns($columns){
    $column_meta = array( 'reported' => 'Reported' );
    $columns = array_slice( $columns, 0, 4, true ) + $column_meta + array_slice( $columns, 6, NULL, true ); 
    return $columns;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter you're looking for is `manage_edit-comments_columns`. Here is a post detailing how to add custom columns to the edit comments section of the admin http://stv.whtly.com/2011/07/27/adding-custom-columns-to-the-wordpress-comments-admin-page/

Comment: okay thanks for the article. However it does not tell anything about sortable manage_edit-comments_sortable_columns